# Find the rate of change in x

Tags: derivatives

$y=(169-x^2)^{0.5}
$
Find the rate of change in $x$ if $y$ increases at a rate of 0.8 units per second when$ y=12
$

I started off with$\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac {dx}{dy}\times \frac {dy}{dt}$ (which is 0.8) but how do I find $\frac {dx}{dy}$if I'm only given the equation of $y$?

Comment: `Y = 12` is solved by `x = 5`. At `x = 5` the derivative of `y(x)` is something, say `C` yUnits per xUnits. You know that the speed is set by 0.8 yUnits per tUnit, but, (0.8 yUnits per tUnit) / (`C` yUnits per xUnits.)  = 0.8/C xUnits pr tUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of $x$ as a function of $y$ from the first equation.

$$x=\sqrt{169-y^2}$$

So,

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{-2y}{2 \sqrt{169-y^2}}=\frac{-y}{ \sqrt{169-y^2}}$$

From this equation you can get the desired value just substituting the values of $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$